# Как отправить get-запрос в Яндекс?

Tags: php, get

Для получения списка заместителей администратора в доках указано что надо отправить методом get вот такой запрос:

```
GET /api2/admin/deputy/list?domain=domain.com HTTP/1.1
Host: pddimp.yandex.ru
PddToken: 123456789ABCDEF0000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Как можно реализовать с помощью php?
Пытался через `file_get_contents` вот так:

```
print_r(file_get_contents('https://pddimp.yandex.ru/api2/admin/deputy/list?domain=mgtcontrol.ru&Pddtoken=123456'));
```

Но не выходит.

Comment: Приходит не ответ, а json файл, причём через txt. Я как раз знаю что говорю

Answer (score 1):

`PddToken` - не `GET` параметр, а кастомный заголовок.

Через `file_get_contents` дополнительный контроль над HTTP-запросами можно получить через механизм [`stream`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php). Например,

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"PddToken: 123456789ABCDEF0000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$response = file_get_contents('https://pddimp.yandex.ru/api2/admin/deputy/list?domain=mgtcontrol.ru', false, $context);
var_dump($response);
```

Получаю в ответ логичное

```
{"domain": "mgtcontrol.ru", "success": "error", "error": "bad_token"}
```

Это уже не `no_auth`, именно логичный ответ про неверный токен.

Или, что привычнее, использовать [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) для взаимодействия.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://pddimp.yandex.ru/api2/admin/deputy/list?domain=mgtcontrol.ru');
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'PddToken: 123456789ABCDEF0000000000000000000000000000000000000'
    ],
]);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Сработало, теперь я хочу не получить список а добавить. Там нужен метод POST. Как этого добиться? буду премного благодарен!

Comment: Вам нужны опции CURLOPT_POST => true и CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => массив значений или urlencoded строка. Для streams не помню.

Comment: попытался curlom приходит просто bool(false)

Answer (score -1):

Что именно "не выходит"?

Ваш код работает и выдаёт у меня `{"domain": "mgtcontrol.ru", "success": "error", "error": "no_auth"}`

Возможно, дело в том, что на сервере может быть [запрещено этой функцией открывать url](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php):

`Для этой функции вы можете использовать URL в качестве имени файла, если была включена опция "fopen wrappers".`

Также возможно, что вы получаете ответ, но не понимаете, как разобрать json? Смотрите тогда в сторону [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php).

В общем, если ответ не подходит -- то уточните вопрос.

Comment: У меня выходит тоже самое .

Comment: приходит такой же ответ как у Вас.

Comment: Формулируйте вопросы чётче -- у меня нет никакого желания ловить минусы за ответы на плохо заданные вопросы, ни тем более отвечать на них. Если проблема в том, что вы получаете no_auth -- то вам нужно смотреть в сторону curl, авторизовываться на сайте при помощи get_file_content можно (см. описание функции параметр context и примерно такой код: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591601/php-file-get-contents-authorization-header ), но не так удобно, как на curl.